# Saving and restoring font settings

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pandoc

I'm using Pandoc to generate a PDF from a Markdown source file, and passing in a custom LaTeX template (effectively a tweaked version of the Pandoc default) to change the style of the final PDF.

I have 30 lines of LaTeX (which someone else wrote) that I want to insert in the template, but these make several changes to the font settings. I only want those changes to apply to these particular lines, but at the moment LaTeX is applying them to the rest of the document.

Is there a way to save the current font settings before these 30 lines of LaTeX, and then restore them afterwards? I don't know (or particularly care) what the current settings are, I just know I want them to be the same before and after.

Edit: What I want is:

[default font settings]
[30 lines of LaTeX with different font settings]
[default font settings]

Edit: Lines I want to insert:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
  \includegraphics[height=18.5mm]{images/flossuksmaller}\hfill {\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont
  \sffamily
  \textbf{news@UK}
  }
  \centerline{
  \small
  \sffamily
  \textit{The newsletter of FLOSS UK, the new name for the UK's oldest Open Systems User Group, UKUUG}
  }
  \centerline{
  \small
  \sffamily
  Published electronically at
  \texttt{http://www.flossuk.org/newsletter}
  }
  \vspace{1 mm}
  \hrule

  \vspace{-1 mm}
  \sffamily
  \bfseries Volume 24, Number 4\vspace{1 mm}
  \hfill
  ISSN 0965-9412\hfill
  % </number>
  December 2015\vspace{0 mm}
  \hrule

  {
  \tableofcontents
  }

  \pagebreak
```

Comment: Why don't you just comment out the lines which changes the font settings?

Comment: Because I want those settings to apply to the 30 lines of LaTeX that I've pulled in (and *only* those 30 lines)

Comment: try wrapping the block with the different settings between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.  (without an example, i can't perform a valid test, but this is what i'd try first.)

Comment: Show the 30 lines you want to insert.

Comment: \begingroup/\endgroup as suggested by barbara should work fine.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\begingroup` sorted it, thanks (if you want to put that as answer I'll accept it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's often possible to isolate or "quarantine" special settings by hiding them
in a group.  braces `{...}` will do this, but i find it much easier to read

```
\begingroup
....
\endgroup
```

this will *not* work for changes that are made globally.  fortunately, in this
case, font resettings are local.