# How can I save and restore fontdimen parameters?

Tags: fonts, typewriter, grouping

I am using the `fontdimen` code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/799/1551) to make spaces stretch in inline code samples (credit to [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz)):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}

\begin{document}
\texttt{\justify\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the effect of this `\justify` command is global: all subsequent `\texttt` material has variable-width spaces, as can be seen by adding an additional `\texttt{\lipsum[1]}` at the end of the document: the previous `\justify` command applies to it as well.

How can I save and restore `\fontdimen` parameters, so as to *locally* change the width and stretch of interword spaces?

Comment: I should add that I've seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308872/saving-and-restoring-font-settings , but grouping does not save and restore font dimensions.

Comment: Please, don't use `minimal`; it's *not* for examples.

Comment: @egreg I copied the example literally from the answer that I linked to; I didn't want to change it in any way.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the values and re-set

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\savefdims{%
\edef\restorefdims{
\fontdimen2\the\font=\the\fontdimen2\font\relax
\fontdimen3\the\font=\the\fontdimen3\font\relax
\fontdimen4\the\font=\the\fontdimen4\font\relax
\fontdimen7\the\font=\the\fontdimen7\font\relax
\hyphenchar\the\font=\the\hyphenchar\font\relax}%
}

\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}

\begin{document}


\texttt{\savefdims
\typeout{\meaning\restorefdims}%
\justify\lipsum[1]\restorefdims}



\texttt{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\typeout` just to show the form of the saved command, the terminal will show (linebreaks added for clarity)

```
macro:->
   \fontdimen 2\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 =5.24995pt\relax
   \fontdimen 3\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 =0.0pt\relax
   \fontdimen 4\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 =0.0pt\relax
   \fontdimen 7\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 =5.24995pt\relax
   \hyphenchar \OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 =-1\relax
```

Answer (score 3):

`\fontdimen` assignments are implicitly global, as described in the TeXbook. Similarly also the assignment of `\hyphenchar` is global.

Instead of changing the `\fontdimen` parameters you can use `\spaceskip` and `\xspaceskip`.

You may define a `\textttj` command that does the job.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textttj}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \hyphenchar\font=`\- % allowing hyphenation
  \setlength{\spaceskip}{0.8em plus 0.4em minus 0.2em}%
  \setlength{\xspaceskip}{1em plus 0.4em minus 0.2em}%
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\AddToHook{cmd/ttfamily/after}{\hyphenchar\font=-1 }

\begin{document}

\textttj{\kant[1]}

\pagebreak

\texttt{\kant[1]}

\end{document}
```

Note that the em for the typewriter font is usually the same as the widths of letters, so I doubled the values.

[image]